# ie7 css rules works in ie developer tool but not in the code.

Tags: css

div disappears in ie7 on position absolute, but when I use ie developer tool and assign any css rules like zoom:1; it works, and when I actually put that in code, it does not work at all.

Comment: You should include a code sample...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed by placing empty  tag right underneath the div that is absolutely positioned.

Answer (score 0):

chances are its just a compatibility issue with IE, try the following

create a CSS page for controlling the positions of your DIV tags, give the DIV tag an ID and a CLASS

Then call the ID by doing the following in your CSS page

```
#ID
{
   //Put your styles here
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp